# IDE gives Error when importing mongodb repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

when I try to import MongoDB repository, IDE gives an error as shown in the image and cannot extends the class I created
I'm using
[image: Importing MongoDB to the spring-boot application]
<sub>(source: [imge.to](https://b.imge.to/2019/08/24/oERvt.png))</sub>

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: Did you use `@EnableMongoRepositories` in your configuration class?

Comment: I tried to add the annotation but the ide returned an error and suggested me to use JPA repository

Comment: Take a look on this site. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html

Comment: Solved thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You have provided with less information but here is the solution for your problem:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I think that you haven't added dependency in your pom.xml